# Spinners and problems with Context?

Tags: android, null, spinner, android-context

I'm working on a fragment class like the next:

```
public class DemandFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener{...
```

I have declared this:

```
Spinner spinner_loc;
ArrayAdapter<String> spinner_loc_adapter = null;

@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle state){

        super.onActivityCreated(state);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        source_category = Integer.parseInt(bundle.getString("category"));

        prepareSpinner();
...
```

And I have the next function that it's called from the onActivityCreated method (to modularize the code):

```
private void prepareSpinner(){

        spinner_loc = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner_loc);
...
```

And further... inside of prepareSpinner() method.

```
spinner_loc = null;
spinner_loc_adapter = null;
spinner_loc_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_content, values);
spinner_loc.setAdapter(spinner_loc_adapter);
spinner_loc_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Value is an array of strings.

**PROBLEM**: I'm getting a null pointer exception on the spinner_loc_adapter. I belive that the error is the context, but I can not figure out why.

What context must be in: Fragment_class -> oncreate() -> prepareSpinner() ??

I've tried with a Context _c in the declaration, and passing it to the adapter in place of getActivity(), but I'm getting the same error.

LogCat

```
03-24 12:51:46.605  12785-12785/com.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.test.fragment.DemandFragment.prepareSpinner(DemandFragment.java:330)
            at com.test.fragment.DemandFragment.onActivityCreated(DemandFragment.java:95)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1508)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/layout_select"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="#1794d4"
                android:alpha="0.9"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="30dp">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="@string/offer_location"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:id="@+id/offer_location" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinner_location"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_button"
                    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
                    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                    android:divider="@drawable/spinner_button"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="@string/choose_brand_model"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spiner_marca"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_button"
                    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
                    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                    android:divider="@drawable/spinner_button"
                    />

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spiner_modelo"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinner_button"
                    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
                    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
                    android:divider="@drawable/spinner_button"
                    />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_disable_spinner"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/dark_blue_text_button"
                    android:text="@string/brand_not_sure"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/dark_blue_border_button"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#cccccc"
                android:text="@string/wanted"
                android:layout_below="@id/layout_select"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/layout_options">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bt_add_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_text"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bt_add_photo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_photo"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/bt_add_audio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_audio"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/layout_type">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_nuevo"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/gray_text_button"
                    android:text="@string/demand_new"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gray_border_button"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_km0"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/gray_text_button"
                    android:text="@string/demand_km0"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gray_border_button"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bt_2mano"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textColor="@drawable/gray_text_button"
                    android:text="@string/demand_used"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    android:background="@drawable/gray_border_button"/>
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageViewSend"
        android:src="@drawable/bt_enviar_solicitud"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#1794d4"
        android:paddingLeft="80dp"
        android:paddingRight="80dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What if you use `getActivity()` instead of `getView()` while preparing the spinner?

Answer (score 1):

Use the bewlow in `onActivtiyCreated` of fragment. `spinner_loc` is likely null coz `getView()` returns null. You need to wait till the activity is created and fragment is attached to the activity

```
spinner_loc = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner_loc);
spinner_loc_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_content, values);
spinner_loc.setAdapter(spinner_loc_adapter);
spinner_loc_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Edit:

```
 <Spinner
 android:id="@+id/spinner_location"
```

Change

```
 spinner_loc = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner_loc);
```

to

```
 spinner_loc = (Spinner) getView().findViewById(R.id.spinner_location);
```

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin then its a case of not referencing the right id. could be verified if you could post the xml

Comment: It's posted. I have changed before the prepareSpinner() method, _c = getActivity().getApplicationContext(); and I've modified spinner_loc_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_content, values); to spinner_loc_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(_c, R.layout.spinner_content, values); BUT THERE IS NO CHANGES. :(

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin still getting NPE??

Comment: Sorry Raghunandan, the xml was fine, It has another name because I have been testing everything I can. Still with NPE.

Comment: well if you have referenced the right id then you should not have NPE. Atleast post the full stacktrace not just 2 or 3 lines. there is a caused by part which indicates where you have the problem and pls make sure you post the right codes so that you don't waste time and mislead others

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin where is spinner_loc in xml?? and which layout is inflated in fragment??

Comment: I said that I was testing things, spinner_location is spinner_loc. But this is not the problem. It's a problem of Context. And Activity calls a Fragment, Fragment (with a layout) calls inside onActivityCreate the method prepareSpinner(), and I think that the context that I pass to the arrayadapter is not correct, but I don't know which is the right context in this situation.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin what context. where is context used. `getActivity()` returns the context this fragment is associated with. that cannot be null.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin even if that was the case stacktrace would have indicated the same. there is problem in initializing views and only objects can be null surely your spinner initialization fails

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin and that is why i am guessing view initialization is null form the time i posted the code in my post

Comment: When your code, is the same NPC, when the line spinner_loc.setAdapter(spinner_loc_adapter) is loaded, the NPC appears.

Comment: @Victor_J_Martin i am done. this is leading to a discussion. good luck

Answer (score 0):

Try to use bellow code

```
View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view,null);
spinner_loc = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_loc);
spinner_loc_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.spinner_content, values);
spinner_loc.setAdapter(spinner_loc_adapter);
spinner_loc_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have the inflater on the onCreateView method:

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_demand, container, false);
    }

And I use getView in the class later.